# Internet Explorer 8, 9 window.open issue

Tags: javascript, html, translation

when opening the code blow in IE 8 and 9 it opens only the **http://translate.google.com/** without the languages codes and the sentences. it works fine in Chrome and Firefox.

```
function DoTransGg(){
window.open('http://translate.google.com/#en|de|I want to travel with him.','_blank')
}
<input type='button' value='Google Translate' onclick='DoTransGg()'>
```

Comment: I tried his code in jsFiddle and tested in IE8/ IE9 and it works without the problem you are seeing. Are you sure there aren't problems with your code elsewhere?

Comment: what do you mean? "No it does not for me"

Comment: I can confirm that IE8 does strip everything after the # when running that line in the console.

Answer (score 1):

IE exhibits this behaviour only when used on localhost. With a remote webserver, it functions correctly, and includes the hash when executing `window.open(url...#...)`.

Comment: After some experimentation, I believe this is the correct answer! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have created a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ByAE3) that works with your provided code, with a small change. I included the use of encodeURIComponent() on the sentence to ensure your URL is formed correctly.

Comment: your solution works when I open it from jsFiddle, but when I save it on a file on my Pc and then open the script in IE, I get the same error.

Comment: Try adding `127.0.0.1 something.com` to your hosts file and then try setting the url on your local machine to something.com to see if it works.

Comment: thx for you suggestion. at this point I don't know how to implement it.